# How do i disable Logitech G430 sidetone/mic monitoring/listening?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone

On windows I got to Settings then sounds, then recording, then advanced, then toggle listen OFF. Then that works and makes it so I cant hear my self.

Tried running the logitech gaming software with wine no success and there is no loopback module running.

Kernel: 4.19.36-1-MANJARO OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64

Comment: And if clicking mute on the headset doesn't work, first step is to look at all ALSA mixers with `amixer` or `alsamixer` (make sure to select the G430 "sound card"), to see if the driver offers a mixer control for that.

Answer (score 1):

Click the MUTE button of the [headset](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-audio/g430-7-1-surround-sound-gaming-headset.html) on its cable.

Answer (score 1):

Open AlsaMixer by typing `alsamixer` into the terminal, then press F6 and select `Logitech G430 Gaming Headset` from the list of available soundcards on your computer. After that, you will be presented with two sliders, one for the volume of your computer audio and one for the volume of the microphone sidetone that you want to get rid of. Select the one that says `Mic` and move it all the way down to zero.

You can now close AlsaMixer again, as that procedure permanently mutes the sidetone of your Logitech G430 headphones.